# Task sequencing based on dependent tasks with parallel execution

Tags: java, algorithm, scala, sequencing

Having a scenario where I need to identify task sequence and execute tasks possible indenpendent flows/tasks parallely. for example

Task 1

Task 2 ->Task 11 and task-3

Task 3 -> Task 1

Task 4 -> Task 8 and task 12

Task 5 -> Task 9

Task 7

Task 8 -> Task 10

Task 9

Task 10

Task 11

each task does some computation, all tasks will respond with a Number. need to collect all task responses  in a Set () and respond to client of the method/function.
independent tasks can compute parallely. Also Algorithm should find if any circular dependency.

Task 1 7,9,10 and 11 are independent

Task 2 dependent on outcome of 11 and 3

Task 3 on 1

Task 4 on 8 and  12

Task 5 on 9

what data structure and algorithm suitable for this problem, could someone help?

Comment: what does "dependent on outcome" mean? Takes results as parameters? Or are we talking side-effects here? How are your tasks represented in code?

Comment: I would suggest using **cats-effect** `IO` to represent the tasks, the  build a DAG of the tasks using a `Map[TaskId, NonEmptySet[TaskId]]` and finally do a a recursion over the DAG and running each set of tasks in parallel.

Comment: Why can't you use some existing orchestration tools? like azkaban, dataflow streamset etc.

Comment: @Dima Yes I meant outcome is input for another task

Comment: @SudhaRajamanickam then just start all the tsks with `Futures`,